# How to use Flutter in Powershell behind a proxy?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I have tried to use the Flutter command line to download the Pub packages from a university computer where I study but, because it uses a proxy with users that, although I own it, still using the steps specified on the page from [Troubleshooting pub](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall), I always get the following error:

```
pub get failed (69)
```

No matter how much I define the environment variables:

```
http_proxy="http://username:password@address:port"
HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@address:port"
or
https_proxy="http://username:password@address:port"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@address:port"
```

That didn't work.

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: The linked to page does not specify the http/https protocol part of the url in the examples.  What happens if you do like the example shows and only specify username:password@hostname:port rather than https://...?  Also, not sure if it's important but you use http:// in both the http and https proxy setting...

Comment: @JJF, When I try to set the environment variable without the http: // I get the following error:Proxy failed to establish tunnel (407 Proxy Authentication Required (Forefront TMG requires authorization to satisfy the request. Access to the web proxy filter has been denied.)) .

I already verified that the user was correct and that he had credentials, after all, he is the same user of the pc that I am using.

Comment: That's all I've got. Sorry.  It sure sounds like a username/password problem.  What about the fact that you used http:// in both the http_proxy *AND* https_proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @JJF, well I had see a lot of examples of how to define the environment variables and the fact that I use http:// in both http_proxy and https_proxy doesn't appear to make ant difference. For to say the true is pretty strange that the problem is relationated with the username:password because is exactly the user and password that I use on Firefox to work behind the proxy. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove protocol from var's, and when you get "Proxy failed to establish tunnel 407 Proxy Authentication Required", just add `jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=` in your jvm options (default in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/net.properties`).

Comment: I'm new to Flutter. Where is jvm options? I what the value should be ?